# What does the "summary" time of the network timing mean?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

What does the "summary" time at the bottom of the network timing info mean?

[image]

Maybe I am missing something, but I cannot find info about this value: i.e. the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation) is very detailed and describes all items, except for the "summary".

I wonder why this time is so high - much higher than the sum of the individual parts above.

Comment: It's `timeEnd - timeStart`, which implicitly includes the huge gap between the bars on your screenshot.

Comment: So it's the time when my js-code starts the request until the browser returns the server data to my js-code. Which implies, that there is nothing that the relevant code can do to reduce this time.

Comment: I guess you should check the other things that happen inside that gap.

Comment: @wOxxOm Right. I think it's not a major issue, because the gap is just large in the development build (where lot's of other things are going on, e.g. a lot of debug messages, etc.). In the production build there is no major issue. Thanks for clarifying what the time actually means.